# Breaking a marginpar over a pagebreak

Tags: marginpar, latex3, marginnote

Is there a way to do this in LaTeX 3?

I looked at [marginpar and orphans](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28729/marginpar-and-orphans), and I am not sure that it addresses my question, but I belive it states that this is not possible in LaTeX 2e.

This is most common for me when I have a marginpar that is tied to text that happens to fall out near the bottom of a page. This also happens if I use marginnote instead.

If someone has ideas for how to post a MWE, let me know and I'll post one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use LaTeX2e if you use a very new (2013/12/19) addition to the KOMA-Script family: the `scrlayer-notecolumn` package. It has a command `\makenote{<note>}` that per default adds a note to the margin.

The package also allows to declare additional “notecolumns” where notes then can be added with `\makenote[<name of notecolumn>]{<note>}`.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

% we need a pagestyle based on `scrlayer-scrpage' for `scrlayer-notecolumn' to
% work:
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}
% a default column `marginpar' is defined. This sets the font for it:
\setkomafont{notecolumn.marginpar}{\raggedright\footnotesize}

% for mock text:
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\makenote{\kant[1-2]}%
\kant[1-8]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a report/article documentclass?

Comment: @soandos just replace `scrartcl` in the above example with `article`: it should work just the same

Comment: Is `scrlayer-scrpage` part of MiKTeX? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @soandos According to http://miktex.org/packages/koma-script v3.12 is which means that `scrlayer`, `scrlayer-scrpage` and `scrlayer-notecolumn` are, too. You probably need to update?

Comment: I am getting strange warnings when I try and compile my document (its a report with a lot of math). I get many "note box `marginpar` empty" messages when as far as I can tell there is nothing about that on the line (for example, its the end of an `align*` environment. Additionally, I get a split note warning on my document. Yours is compiling cleanly. Any ideas?

Comment: @soandos I don't have many experiences with said package (as I said: it is very new). I don't know what the first message means. The second simply seems to tell the the note has been broken over a page boundary... I get that, too, with my example.

Comment: @soandos: As long as the result is what you want, you can ignore the warning. It is useful, when someone does _not_ want to have the margin content broken. The package cannot know your intention.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think margin paragraphs can easily be broken over a page. The [`marginfix`](http://ctan.org/pkg/marginfix) package was designed to address the problem that

> Authors using LaTeX to typeset books with significant margin material often run
>   into the problem of long notes running off the bottom of the page. ... This package implements a solution to make marginpars ”just work” by keeping a list of floating inserts and arranging them intelligently in the output routine.